# Hadoop Heartbeat Message Exchange

Tags: hadoop

I want to exchange heartbeat message in hadoop yarn. In hadoop mapreduce1 we can exchange heartbeat message between job tracker and task tracker. how can i achieve it in yarn.

Answer (score 0):

`Heartbeat` is implemented in `YARN` as well. That is the core concept of communication with the `Data nodes` to the `Name nodes`. `Containers` communicate with `ApplicationMaster` and `Node Managers` sends Heart beats to the `Resource manager` as well.
You also can implement this by running background threads always on some specific ports and
listens the requests. You can create background threads, refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877096/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-java-thread) and [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365795/best-way-to-create-a-background-thread-in-java)
Please have a look at this image for better understanding.
[image]
Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your guidance sir. But actually my question is e.g in mapreduce1 with help of TaskTrackerAction class we can send our user defined heart beat messages from jobtracker to tasktracker similarly is there any way to send user defined hearbeat messages in YARN (maprdeuce1).  And you tell me which API i should use for that.

Comment: what is your intension of custom heartbeat messages ? what you want to do ?

Comment: Sir while reading one article in that article they used custom heartbeat messages where what they did is tasktracker will compute some data of its local maps then once it will computed it will notify jobracker about there calculation. In same way Jobtracker will collect computed map data from all tasktrackers and again perform some computation on collected data and send notification to tasktracker. like that. For this they used some TaskTrackerAction class so if it is possible how can i achieve it in YARN and using which API.